# Scrapy Spider doesn't insert data to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I am new to Python and the code I wrote is not working as I expected. I try to insert an item by Scrapy Spider to a MySQL database, but when I check the database there is no that item.

My pipeline code is below.

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode


class LyricsPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()
        # self.create_table()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            passwd='',
            database='lyrical'
        )
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    # def create_table(self):
    #     self.curr.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS llyrics""")
    #     self.curr.execute("""create table llyrics (
    #         title text,
    #         movie text,
    #         lyrics text
    #     )""")
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.store_db(item)
        return item

    def store_db(self, item):
        self: curr.execute("""insert into mylyrics values ('title','movie','lyrics')""", (
            item['title'][0],
            item['movie'][0],
            item['lyrics'][0]
        ))
        self.conn.commit()
```

What am I missing, could you please advise me?

Comment: What is the variable `item` you haven't defined it here. Also, it may not be generating an error because you are not calling the function `process_item`...hence the `store_db()` function is not being called.

Comment: I would recommend amending your code to run the `store_db()` function and define `item` then come back with a question and an error if necessary

Comment: Do you get any error in the logs?

Answer (score -1):

I assume that the item is properly passed to this function, and you get it from pipeline - also your pipeline is added in settings like:
`setting.py`

```py
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'some_spider.pipelines.SpiderDataPipeline': 300,
}
```

where 300 is its importance (for more check on scrapy documentation - [Scrapy pipeline doc](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#activating-an-item-pipeline-component)).

Second thing can be your function `store_db`. Try that:

```py
def store_db(self, item):
    self.curr.execute("insert into mylyrics values (%s,%s,%s)", (
        item['title'][0],
        item['movie'][0],
        item['lyrics'][0]
    ))
    self.conn.commit()
```

Hope that this will help you solve the problem.

Comment: This will not solve the problem...`item` is stll undefined. Also your use of string formatting `%s` hasn't been used correctly.

Comment: Item is passed in scrapy in pipeline.
Why %s are wrong? Check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: You have misunderstood, look at the arguments for `store_db()`...`item` is not defined.

Comment: Am I missing something? `self.store_db(item)` is called by `def process_item(self, item, spider)`, which gets item from pipeline - item is defined in other piece of code.